# Hashmap Entries don't get into Columns

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, jtable

```
package einlesen;

/**
 * @author a
 *
 */

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowSorter;
import javax.swing.SortOrder;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class Einlesen {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    static List<String> word = new ArrayList<String>();
    static Map<String, Integer> wordsInTheMiddle = new HashMap<>();
    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource" })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String antwort;

        System.out.println("Welches Dokument wollen Sie? Geben Sie dabei den Path an, bitte.");
        antwort = ("Downloads/lol.txt"); // scan.nextLine();

        String path = System.getProperty("user.home");
        // System.out.println(path);
        File file = Paths.get(path, antwort).toFile();

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(br);
        //List<String> word = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String wort = sc.next();
            // Remove quotes
            if (wort.startsWith("\"")) {
                wort = wort.substring(1);
            }
            if (wort.endsWith("\"")) {
                wort = wort.substring(0, wort.length() - 1);
            }
            word.add(wort);
        }

        br.close();

        int chunkStartIndex = 0;
        Map<String, Integer> wordsInTheMiddle = new HashMap<>();
        while (word.size() - chunkStartIndex > 0) {

            int chunkEndIndex = chunkStartIndex + 2000;
            if (chunkEndIndex > word.size()) {
                chunkEndIndex = word.size();
            }
            List<String> chunkOfWords = word.subList(chunkStartIndex, chunkEndIndex);

            for (int i = 0; i < chunkOfWords.size(); i++) {

                String word1 = chunkOfWords.get(i);

                if (word1.matches("[A-Z][a-z][a-z]\\w+")) {

                    wordsInTheMiddle.putIfAbsent(word1, 0);
                    int oldCount = wordsInTheMiddle.get(word1);
                    wordsInTheMiddle.put(word1, oldCount + 1);

                }
            }

            // do not process the last word! Would cause an index out of bounds exception.
            for (int i = 0; i < chunkOfWords.size() - 1; i++) {

                String word1 = chunkOfWords.get(i);

                if (word1.matches("\\w*(\\.|\\?|!)$")) {

                    // Word is at end of sentence
                    String nextWord = chunkOfWords.get(i + 1);

                    if (wordsInTheMiddle.getOrDefault(nextWord, 0) < 2) {

                        // sort out words that appear at the beginning of a sentence and appear less
                        // than 2 times in the text
                        wordsInTheMiddle.remove(nextWord);

                    }

                }

            }

            // remove blacklisted words
            String[] blacklist = { "This", "When", "Night", "Most", "Stone", "There", "Bonfire", "Tuesday", "Their",
                    "They", "Professor", "Famous", "About", "Madam", "Nearly", "Aunt", "What", "Uncle", "Mommy",
                    "Scars", "Scotch", "Every", "That" };
            for (String listedWord : blacklist) {

                wordsInTheMiddle.remove(listedWord);

            }

            System.out.println("Mitte: " + wordsInTheMiddle);

            chunkStartIndex = chunkEndIndex;

        }


        JTable t = new JTable(toTableModel(wordsInTheMiddle));

        TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(t.getModel());
        t.setRowSorter(sorter);

        List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>(25);
        sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(1, SortOrder.DESCENDING));
        sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(t);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.add(p);
        f.setSize(700, 600);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setTitle(antwort);

    }


    public static TableModel toTableModel(Map<?, ?> map) {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[] { "Key", "Value" }, 0);
        for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            model.addRow(new Object[] { entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() });

            for (int a = word.size()/2000;model.getColumnCount() - 2 <= a;)
            {
                model.addColumn(new Object[] { wordsInTheMiddle});

            }

        }

        return model;

    }

}
```

So this is my code for a Programm that divides a text into different parts with 2000 words and counts the appaerance of names in the different parts. This was done in a Hashmap. So I need a table for that hashmap, where I can see the name, the total count, and the count per Part. the first column is the name, the Second the total count and the rest are the different parts.

Like this:

```
name | total count | 1.Part | 2.Part...
---------------------------------------
name | namecounttotal| count1.Part| count2.Part...
```

I got the first two columns with the correct entries, but in the rest of the columns I somehow can't enter the values. I Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your program:

1. You don't seem to keep track of how many names are there in each 2,000 word chunck. You can solve this issue by adding e.g. `List<Map<String,Integer>>` or another datatype. In my example, each of the elements of the list would keep track of the names and their count in that specific chunck.
2. Your `tableToModel()` does add new columns for each of the 2,000 word chuncks with `.addColumn()`. However, when you add a row with `.addRow(Object[])`, the Object array holds only two elements. You need to wrap the chunck-specific counts into that Object array somehow. Furthermore, it might be reasonable to first create the columns with `.addColumn()` and then later add the new row at once.

Here's something that I would do to address those issues:

1. Add the data to the chunck-specific counter and keep track of the number of the chunck:

   ```
   List<Map<String,Integer>> wordsPerChunck = new ArrayList<>();

   while (word.size() - chunkStartIndex > 0) {

       // Initialize a chunck-specific word counter
       Map<String, Integer> countInChunck = new HashMap<>();
       wordsPerChunck.add(countInChunck);
       ...
       for (int i = 0; i < chunkOfWords.size(); i++) {

           String word1 = chunkOfWords.get(i);

           if (word1.matches("[A-Z][a-z][a-z]\\w+")) {

               wordsInTheMiddle.putIfAbsent(word1, 0);
               wordsInTheMiddle.put(word1, oldCount + 1);
               countInChunck.putIfAbsent(word1, 0);
               // Increase the count in this chunck
               countInChunck.put(word1, countInChunck.get(word1) + 1);

           }
       }
   ```
2. Modify the `toTableModel` a bit: Take that list as the second parameter. Create the columns first, and then create a correct-sized `Object` array that holds the name, total count and the chunck-specific counts:

   ```
   public static TableModel toTableModel(Map<?, ?> map, List<?> list) {
       DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[] { "Key", "Value" }, 0);
       for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {

           for (int a = word.size()/2000; model.getColumnCount() - 2 <= a;) {
               model.addColumn(new Object[] { "partial" });
           }

           // Create the object that holds all the columns
           Object[] temp = new Object[2+list.size()];
           temp[0] = entry.getKey();
           temp[1] = entry.getValue();

           int index = 2;
           for (Object o : list) {

               Map<?, ?> m = (Map<?, ?>) o;
               // Get the chunck-specific count with the correct key (the name)
               temp[index] = m.get(temp[0]);
               index++;
           }
           model.addRow(temp);
       }
   ```

I didn't implement here the checks that you have made. But if you fix those, you should be able to get it working.

Create the `JTable` then with:

```
JTable t = new JTable(toTableModel(wordsInTheMiddle, wordsPerChunck));
```

Comment: with Checks what do you mean? And thank you for your help

Comment: I mean that you use `wordsInTheMiddle.remove(...)` to remove some blacklisted words for example. But that should be trivial to implement.

Comment: I know, I'm an idiot...but how? I testen it without the check and nothing happened

Comment: It says it has a Problem with : `int oldCount = wordsInTheMiddle.get(word1);`

Comment: What kind of a problem is it?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at einlesen.Einlesen.main(Einlesen.java:88)

Comment: You have probably removed the line where you initially set the value to `0` with `putIfAbsent` method. For clarification, I have omitted some lines from the copy-paste with `...` to make it a bit shorter. You should keep the existing code as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Am9417 I got it! Here is the result if someone is interested:

```
    package einlesen;

/**
 * @author angeliqueschulberger
 *
 */

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowSorter;
import javax.swing.SortOrder;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class Einlesen {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    static List<String> word = new ArrayList<String>();
    static Map<String, Integer> wordsInTheMiddle = new HashMap<>();
    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource" })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String antwort;

        System.out.println("Welches Dokument wollen Sie? Geben Sie dabei den Path an, bitte.");
        antwort = ("Downloads/lol.txt"); // scan.nextLine();

        String path = System.getProperty("user.home");
        // System.out.println(path);
        File file = Paths.get(path, antwort).toFile();

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(br);
        //List<String> word = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String wort = sc.next();
            // Remove quotes
            if (wort.startsWith("\"")) {
                wort = wort.substring(1);
            }
            if (wort.endsWith("\"")) {
                wort = wort.substring(0, wort.length() - 1);
            }
            word.add(wort);
        }

        br.close();

        int chunkStartIndex = 0;
        Map<String, Integer> wordsInTheMiddle = new HashMap<>();

        List<Map<String,Integer>> wordsPerChunck = new ArrayList<>();
        int chunckNumber = 0;

        while (word.size() - chunkStartIndex > 0) {

            int chunkEndIndex = chunkStartIndex + 2000;
            if (chunkEndIndex > word.size()) {
                chunkEndIndex = word.size();
            }
            List<String> chunkOfWords = word.subList(chunkStartIndex, chunkEndIndex);

            Map<String, Integer> countInChunck = new HashMap<>();
            wordsPerChunck.add(countInChunck);

            for (int i = 0; i < chunkOfWords.size(); i++) {

                String word1 = chunkOfWords.get(i);

                if (word1.matches("[A-Z][a-z][a-z]\\w+")) {
                    wordsInTheMiddle.putIfAbsent(word1, 0);
                    int oldCount = wordsInTheMiddle.get(word1);
                    wordsInTheMiddle.put(word1, oldCount + 1);
                    countInChunck.putIfAbsent(word1, 0);
                    // Increase the count in this chunck
                    countInChunck.put(word1, countInChunck.get(word1) + 1);

                }
            }

            // do not process the last word! Would cause an index out of bounds exception.
            for (int i = 0; i < chunkOfWords.size() - 1; i++) {

                String word1 = chunkOfWords.get(i);

                if (word1.matches("\\w*(\\.|\\?|!)$")) {

                    // Word is at end of sentence
                    String nextWord = chunkOfWords.get(i + 1);

                    if (wordsInTheMiddle.getOrDefault(nextWord, 0) < 2) {

                        // sort out words that appear at the beginning of a sentence and appear less
                        // than 2 times in the text
                        wordsInTheMiddle.remove(nextWord);

                    }

                }

            }

            // remove blacklisted words
            String[] blacklist = { "This", "When", "Night", "Most", "Stone", "There", "Bonfire", "Tuesday", "Their",
                    "They", "Professor", "Famous", "About", "Madam", "Nearly", "Aunt", "What", "Uncle", "Mommy",
                    "Scars", "Scotch", "Every", "That" };
            for (String listedWord : blacklist) {

                wordsInTheMiddle.remove(listedWord);

            }


            System.out.println("Mitte: " + wordsInTheMiddle);

            chunkStartIndex = chunkEndIndex;

        }


        JTable t = new JTable(toTableModel(wordsInTheMiddle, wordsPerChunck));

        TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(t.getModel());
        t.setRowSorter(sorter);

        List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>(25);
        sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(1, SortOrder.DESCENDING));
        sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(t);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.add(p);
        f.setSize(700, 600);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setTitle(antwort);

    }


    public static TableModel toTableModel(Map<?, ?> map, List<Map<String, Integer>> list) {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[] { "Key", "Value" }, 0);
        for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {

            for (int a = word.size()/2000;model.getColumnCount() - 2 <= a;)
            {
                model.addColumn(new Object[] { "partial" });

            }
            Object[] temp = new Object[2+list.size()];
            temp[0] = entry.getKey();
            temp[1] = entry.getValue();

            int index = 2;
            for (Object o : list) {

                Map<?, ?> m = (Map<?, ?>) o;
                // Get the chunck-specific count with the correct key (the name)
                temp[index] = m.get(temp[0]);
                index++;
            }
            model.addRow(temp);

        }

        return model;

    }
}
```